# Strange performance issues (blocking?) with ASP.NET Core web application

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, .net-core

We're preparing to deploy one of our first ASP.NET Core applications, and seeing some very strange performance issues on our staging web server. Everything seems fine on development machines, either running in IIS Express, or a test site set up in regular IIS that closely mirrors the config on the web server.

The code doesn't seem to be doing anything unusual, but when running on the web server, just seems to enter a kind of fugue state / lock up from time to time. The logs don't indicate any problems *per se*, but the timestamps have some very long and unexpected gaps when running on that machine.

The application is .NET Core 2.2, running in-process on IIS. The local machines are Windows 10, the server is Windows Server 2012r2. The web server is a shared machine, with other sites configured on it, but this application is a separate site, and a separate app pool, from any of the others.

Here's a snippet of API controller code, which invokes a method on a service component to authenticate the user against an external system:

```cs
AuthenticationResult result;
try {
  _logger.LogTrace("Will attempt user authentication for source {1} {2}", source.Id, source.Name);
  result = await system.AttemptUserAuthenticationAsync(model);
  if( null == result?.ExternalKey ) {
    return UserInformationResult.Empty;
  }
}
catch( ValidationException ex ) {
  _logger.LogTrace(ex, "Validation failed for authentication submission for source {1} {2}", source.Id, source.Name);
  return ValidationProblem(ex.ModelState);
}
```

Here's the validation code in one of the `AttemptUserAuthenticationAsync()` implementations:

```cs
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
if( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(credentials.Username) ) {
  validationResults.Add(new ValidationResult(_localizer["Please provide a username"], new[] { nameof(credentials.Username) }));
}
if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Password) ) {
  validationResults.Add(new ValidationResult(_localizer["Please provide a password"], new[] { nameof(credentials.Password) }));
}
if( validationResults.Any() ) {
  _logger.LogTrace("Authentication credentials invalid; will throw ValidationException");
  throw new Models.ValidationException(validationResults);
}
```

Here's what the log looks like when this code is executed on the troublesome web server, with an interval of **three minutes** between where the exception is about to be thrown, and where it's caught in the invoking code. This particular issue seems pretty consistent. On team workstations, the gap in the log here is a matter of a few milliseconds.

```
2020-01-15 10:38:26.969 -05:00 [VRB] Authentication credentials invalid; will throw ValidationException
2020-01-15 10:41:29.859 -05:00 [VRB] Validation failed for authentication submission for source "b8c28eac-09e4-4a0c-82a1-b1b788c04467" Test Source
```

I'm kind of at a loss for where to go with this problem. Are there settings we should look at? Other logs? What might be causing this application to block like this?

Comment: `AttemptUserAuthenticationAsync` is async, but the snippet you've chosen to post has nothing async or even notable happening in it. What's actually happening async there?

Comment: I didn't include it because in the case I'm talking about, execution never gets there, and it didn't seem relevant. But if validation succeeds, we're calling an external API with those credentials to get information about the user.

Answer (score 0):

Do consider handling long-running requests with background services or out of process with an Azure Function. Completing work out-of-process is especially beneficial for CPU-intensive tasks.
Do use real-time communication options, such as SignalR, to communicate with clients asynchronously.

Comment: OK. But the whole problem is that this _shouldn't be_ a long-running request in the case where the model validation fails. And, on development machines, it isn't.